# Ldap certificates expired on a WebSphere application server initially configured with ldap

Tags: ssl, ldap, certificate, websphere, websphere-8

We are running WebSphere Application Server v8.5 on AIX 7, which we configured to use ldap security. Everything is working fine, but project went halt for some time and our WAS was down. Now we see that ldap cerficates were expired, hence we are unable to connect to dmgr & admin console. Can somebody help to resolve it?
We know how to configure ldap on WAS, but dont no how to change expired ldap cerficate with new cerficates. (We received new non-expiry certificates from ldap team but dont no how to configure it on WAS).

Answer (score 1):

You need to disable security, restart dmgr, replace certificates and reenable security.

To disable security:

- stop/kill the dmgr
- run the following from the `dmgr\bin` folder:

  ```
  wsadmin -conntype NONE
  ```

At the wsadmin prompt, type `securityoff` and then type `exit`.

Restart your dmgr.

**UPDATE**

Do you have Federated or Standalone Ldap configured? You should have in LDAP configuration link to SSL configuration. There you will need to add your new certificate to the Signers store (this is very simplified description as I'm not sure which repository you are using).